# Jquery dialog, javascript

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a jquery dialog with an input text and some checkboxes.

The problem is that i cant set focus or enter text in the inputs,

I am using jqueryui 1.7.3 and 1.3.2 core, firefox 3.6.10?

On IE the problem doesn't exist, so is this a bug of jquery or firefox?

Any solutions?
thanks

code:

```
    $('#corr_types').dialog({
    width:160,
    title: 'Set correction type',
    open:function()
    {
        //input temporani della form
        $(this).find("input:radio").attr('checked','');
        $(this).find("input:radio[value="+type+"]").attr('checked','checked');

        $(this).find("input:checkbox").attr('checked',mpc);
        $(this).find("input:text").val(catno).focus();
    },
    close: function() { 
        $(this).dialog( "destroy" );
    }
});


    <div id="corr_types"  class="corrtypes" style="display:none;" >
<input type=checkbox  >MPC<br /> Catno. <input type="text" size=10 
</div>
```

Comment: Which dialog is this?  Do you have some code to share with us?

Comment: This is most likely to be a problem with your code. All this will have been shown to work with the libs you are using. So, we will need to see your code before we can help you.

Comment: yes i post code, to note that i have more than one dialog in the windows opened

Comment: The code you posted is running fine for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/EP4af/1/ but not in all browsers perhaps?

Comment: I see thanks, but I have still the problem, maybe cause i have to many dialogs?

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
<input type=checkbox  >MPC<br /> Catno. <input type="text" size=10
```

Should be

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mpc" />MPC<br /> Catno. <input type="text" size="10"/>
```

Comment: yes i know I write and copy here just for indicating the code